# How do I point a menu item to a component's task?

Tags: joomla

How do I point a Joomla menu item to a specific task in my custom component?  I have had no trouble creating menu items that point to my views, and each view is available in the list when I select my component in the menu.  But I have not found a way to route the menu to one of my component's tasks.

In some cases, I am using a controller method (i.e. a task) to decide which models and views to present to the user.  Usually this is when I need to display data from multiple models, or I need to use information in the session state to determine which view is appropriate for the user.  It is in these cases that I need a menu item that points to the task.

So, how do I get a menu item to bring a user to "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=do.something"?

What have I tried already, you ask?  I've looked at just about every Google reference I could find, and none seem to address this issue.  I'm either looking for the wrong thing, or it's so dead easy that nobody has ever had to ask for help.  I have also looked through the Joomla components & menu items, finding no examples of a menu item pointing to a controller task.

Comment: You can add a field to the request fieldset. Name it task. The value would be "do.something".  Make the field type="hidden".

Comment: Thank you - that did the job.  Will you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the above answer not flexible enough and finally found this to work perfectly, you can override the menu item form xml ( administrator/components/com_menus/models/forms/item.xml ) and make the link field editable so you can add any request parameters you want, including tasks.

Make sure you leave/add the view name of the request as otherwise the link type cannot be determined, so add it even if it is not relevant eg. &view=yourview.

See system plugin onContentPrepareForm below

```php
    function onContentPrepareForm(&$form, $data) {

        $option = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('option');

        // allow us to edit the link field of the menu item for this component to include some custom request values
        if($option == 'com_menus' && $data->type=='component' && $data->request['option']=='com_your_component_name'){

            $form->setFieldAttribute('link','readonly','false');

        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a field to the request fieldset. Name it task. The value would be "do.something". Make the field `type="hidden"`.

I'm suggesting the hidden because you really don't want the users to be able to change it.

The request fieldset is for fields that go into the url directly with the format `&name=value`.

Comment: Good explanation of the request fieldset. Wish I had read that sentence a long time ago.